# LEFT JOIN not working if I use WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

I have two table called tbl_calendar and tbl_affiliates_link_history, tbl_calendar I am using for fill missing dates in result.
If I use query like below its work fine

```
SELECT dates as date,COUNT(a.id)AS total_visits FROM tbl_calendar as c LEFT JOIN tbl_affiliates_link_history as a ON c.dates = DATE(a.link_visit_time) WHERE c.dates > '2022-02-01' AND c.dates < '2022-02-13' GROUP BY c.dates
```

and giving me result like below

[image]

But if I add one additional where condition in my query called `a.affiliate_id='wilson'`

It's giving me only one result instead of full result like first image

[image]

My second query is like this

```
SELECT dates as date,COUNT(a.id)AS total_visits FROM tbl_calendar as c LEFT JOIN tbl_affiliates_link_history as a ON c.dates = DATE(a.link_visit_time) WHERE c.dates > '2022-02-01' AND c.dates < '2022-02-13'AND a.affiliate_id='wilson' GROUP BY c.dates
```

Comment: At a guess I'd say there's only one row that matches your condition.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, Yes You are right but if there no any row, I want add 0 for the date, thats the reason I am using tbl_calendar for fill missing date with 0

Comment: @HinaPatel Your first example shows 0 total visits for most dates, presumably because there are no matching affiliates for those dates. How is that different from what you are looking for?

Comment: @kmoser first query have not where condition called a.affiliate_id='wilson'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the LEFT JOIN properties, if the record doesn't join with another record into the joining table, all fields of the logical table created with the join are NULL.

This means if you search anything on the joined table on NULL field the search automatically excludes the NULL fields and at this point you are using the LEFT JOIN as an INNER JOIN.

To solve this, you need to add  `OR field IS NULL` to the WHERE condition to keep the NULL results. The second query should be:

```
SELECT dates as date, COUNT(a.id) AS total_visits 
FROM tbl_calendar as c 
LEFT JOIN tbl_affiliates_link_history as a ON c.dates = DATE(a.link_visit_time) 
WHERE c.dates > '2022-02-01' AND c.dates < '2022-02-13' AND 
      (a.affiliate_id='wilson' OR a.affiliate_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY c.dates
```